# How to set up my Desktop PC to work with my Samsung

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an Acer desktop PC that once upon a time was connected via Verizon dsl. Now I have moved to an area where there is nothing available so I have been using my Verizon Samsung as a hotspot with my laptops but can't figure out how to get my desktop PC set up - I did tether it once and it chewed through so much of my data plan that is not doable - are there devices that I can get that would allow me to set up my PC with my cell phone WiFi hotspot??

Comment: If you turned on tethering (internet sharing in settings) you can connect your laptop to your Samsung Windows phone. Then your laptop will use the wireless internet connection and will use some of your data plan. This fact will be the same regardless of the device you are using. No device can magically connect to the internet without a data connection - mobile phones are using mobile networks, routers land lines, etc.

Comment: The cheapest and easiest solution is to buy a USB wifi dongle for your Desktop PC?